# XCode Disable TV-Out WIndow

Tags: xcode, simulator

I somehow enabled TV-Out in Xcode, and the window annoyingly appears every time I run a simulator.  How can I disable it / hide it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When the simulator is running, go to the *Hardware->External Displays* menu and select **Disabled**.

Comment: it tooks me 2 hours too

Comment: it took me 2 days before i bothered googling, many thanks lol